# when adaboost is better than XGboost in some data combinations?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

my name is  Eslam a masters' student in Egypt, my thesis is in the field of education data mining. I used AdaBoost and XGBoost techniques for my predictive model to predict students success rate based on Open Learning Analytics data-set - OLAD.

the idea behind the analysis is tying various techniques (including ensemble and non ensemble techniques) on different combinations of features,interesting results showed up

Results:

[image]

the question is why some techniques performs better than others in specific features combinations? specially for Random Rorest,XGB and ADA?

Comment: ML models differ among other things in the function they fit to the training data. For a given data distribution some models are always better suited than others. For many different data distributions (through sets of features) the model that is best suited (= achieves the highest accuracy) will not always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML model could achieve different results based on what kind of space and what kind of function you want to approximate. You can expect that SVM achieve highest score on data which are naturally embedded on Hilbert space. On the other hand if data does not fit this kind of space (i.e. many categorical, not ordered features) you can expect boosting trees methods would outperform SVM.

However if I good understood that 'Decision Tree Accuracy' is a single decision tree based on results from the picture I believe your tests was done on small data sets or your boosting and RF was incorrectly parametrized.